# Cannot flush the DNS on Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Tags: macos

I have an absolutely bizarre problem and it has STUMPED me..

I cannot seem to flush the DNS on my Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I have tried `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` , i've tried `dscacheutil -flushcache` and it hasn't worked.

I'm building a website, and changed the directories yesterday. Now when I check it on my other machine, it works fine. When I get somewhere from distance to check, it works fine, but it's seemingly stuck in the DNS on this machine as the CSS is not showing.

Is there a hard-flush method (if that makes sense)? The two above did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like browser cache than DNS cache, if you only changed directories.

Try disable and empty browser cache.